# Variable buffer maximizing mean raster

Tags: qgis, point, buffer

I was wondering if it exists a way to create variable buffers where the radius is given by a process of maximization of the mean value of a raster.

I have a point vector data and I would like to create variable circular buffers around these points where the variable distance is given by a process of maximization. In particular, the variable distance has to be the one that maximize the mean population in the buffer zone (and I have a raster of the population in a given country).

In the end should be something like in the picture but the radius should be the result of the maximization process described above.

There is some plugin able to do that?

[image]

Comment: Raster data cannot be buffered, you need vector data.

Comment: Sorry for my inaccuracy in posing the question.

I have a point-vector data and I would like to create circular buffer zones around these point where the radius is given by a process of maximization of the mean of the underling raster

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly. Also, could you explain what "a process of maximization of the mean of the underlying raster" does mean (to you)?

Comment: Again sorry. I have edited my question. Now it is clear what I mean?

Comment: So... your buffer should be of such a size, that the mean population inside it is the highest possible value?

Comment: Exactly! I'm so going crazy with that!

Comment: I hate your problem. What software are you working with?

Comment: Yeah, me too. Qgis

Comment: Some more questions: Is the raster containing the population data a real raster? Or also vector data? Could you provide an example? Also, how does your point data look like - is it regular, or clustered, was it created manually or automatically?

Comment: The raster containing the population is a real raster ( it is this one https://www.worldpop.org/geodata/summary?id=3858 )

My point data are centroids of a polygon created with qgis.

Comment: Can you also provide an example for what your buffer layer should look like in the end?

Comment: I have edited the question in order to give you an idea

Comment: Sorry, I can't wrap my head around this, no real idea how to achieve this.